# Issue in validation in react autocomplete in multiple select using formik

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, formik

I am trying to validate the autocomplete multiple select using the formik. First time it is working on button click but when I remove the selected value then it is not validation.

```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
    import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
    import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
    import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
    import * as Yup from 'yup';
    const cities = [{
    state: "Illinois",
    name: "Chicago",
    id: 3,
    }, {
    state: "Texas",
    name: "Houston",
    id: 2
    }, {
    state: "California",
    name: "Los Angeles",
    id: 1
    }, {
    state: "New York",
    name: "New York City",
    id: 4
    }];
    const initialValues = {
    city_id: '',
    };
    
    const submit = values => {
    let city=JSON.parse(values.city_id);
    };
    
    const SignupForm = () => {
    return (
    <Formik initialValues={initialValues}
    validationSchema = {
    Yup.object().shape({
    city_id: Yup.string().max(255).required('City is required')
    })
    }
    onSubmit={submit}>
    {({ handleChange,touched,errors, values, setFieldValue }) => (
    <Form>
      <Autocomplete
       multiple
        id="city_id"
        name="city_id"
        options={cities}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        onChange={(e, value) => {
          console.log(value);
          let val=JSON.stringify(value);
          setFieldValue(
            "city_id",
            value !== null ? val : initialValues.city_id
          );
        }}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            error={Boolean(touched.city_id && errors.city_id)}
            helperText={touched.city_id && errors.city_id}
            margin="normal"
            label="Cities"
            fullWidth
            name="city_id"
            {...params}
          />
        )}
      />
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
    )}
    </Formik>
    );
    }
    export default SignupForm;
```

Please provide better validation option if I have made mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Validation will not run because `value` is never empty.

If you want to run validation, do:

```
setFieldValue(
  "city_id",
  value
);
```

above code will trigger validation because `value` will be `""` when you remove.

Comment: on doing that new issue arised. That I solved it by usiing JSON.stringfy before.city_id must be a `string` type, but the final value was: `[
  {
    "state": "\"Illinois\"",
    "name": "\"Chicago\"",
    "id": "3"
  }
]`. And this is comming again after doing that.

Comment: city_id must be a `string` type, but the final value was: `[
  {
    "state": "\"Illinois\"",
    "name": "\"Chicago\"",
    "id": "3"
  }
]`.

Comment: Your answer was helpful. Just now issue is resolved. I had to change in setFieldValue.This is new setFieldValue changes.
setFieldValue(
 "city_id",
 Object.keys(value).length!=0 ? val : initialValues.city_id
);

Thank You for support.